# Git won't let me delete a file that starts with :

Tags: git

I'm trying to delete a file named :w from the repo.
Tried `git rm :w` at first, but on error I decided to just removed it thinking I would use magit later to stage the deleting. Magit failed with the same error

```
fatal: pathspec 'w' did not match any files
```

So apparently git is interpreting the : as a special character. Tried escaping it with `\:` to no avail. Any idea what is the problem at hand?

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMp8S.jpg

Comment: glad i'm not the only one who accidentally creates files named `:w`

Comment: what about `git rm ":w"`?

Comment: Using `--` is universal answer to stuff like this, including removing file called -f: `rm -- -f`

Comment: having such filenames is recipe for trouble -- on windows : starts alternate stream within file... I'd suggest avoiding them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any of these should work:

```
git rm "\:w"
git rm ./:w
git rm $PWD/:w
git rm :::w
```

The [man page for git rm](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rm.html) seems to suggest that `git rm -- :w` would work but it treats the files as [pathspecs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html#def_pathspec) and not pure filesystem paths. `:::w` works because a leading `:` in a pathspec marks the beginning of a "magic signature" and you end the signature with another `:`. The reset is treated as the path.

Comment: This does *not* work with Git version 1.8.3.1. If it actually works for you, please provide a Git version number.

Comment: Will try soon, on the buss :) also you can try ./:w or absolute path $PWD/:w

Comment: The original solution you posted doesn't work, but the ones in your comments do becase the path separator keeps `:w` from being interpreted as a refspec.

Comment: `git rm --` did not work for me either. I've updated my answer and also figured why it does not work. Plus a bonus solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me on git 1.8.3:

```
git rm -- "\:w"
```

Answer (score -1):

### Delete File, Then Commit Tree

Git is interpreting your filename as a pathspec. One way to work around this is by removing the file from the working tree, and then committing the new tree. For example:

```
$ rm :w
$ git commit -av
```

Comment: What if you have many changed or even untracked files you do not want to commit right now? This solution will commit them all (`-a`), which is hardly desired.

Comment: @mvp Then use a different solution. Not every solution attempts to solve for all use cases. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Use "git stash" on all the files you don't want to commit. Do the commit, then "git stash pop"